# (c++)Как изменить значение консоли? Как можно регистрировать нажатие клавиш?

Tags: c++, массивы, консоль

Я начал изучать c++ недавно и хотел бы узнать ответы на вопросы:

1. Как можно изменять значение консоли без еще одного вывода массива?
2. Как можно регистрировать нажатия клавиш?
3. Как можно улучшить код снизу?
   Заранее спасибо

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int args, char **argv)
{
    //Генерация карты
    const int WIDTH = 10;
    const int HEIGHT = 20;
    string map[WIDTH][HEIGHT] = {"*"};
    
    //Заполнение карты
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; ++j) {
            map[i][j] = "#";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    //Заполнение полом
    for (int i = 1; i < WIDTH-1; ++i) {
        for (int j = 1; j < HEIGHT-1; ++j) {
            map[i][j] = "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    //Установка персонажа
    int y = WIDTH/2;
    int x = HEIGHT/2;
    map[y][x] = "X";
    
    //Первый запуск карты

    //Передвижение персонажа
    string action = "";
    do {
        //Отображение карты
        for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; ++j) {
                cout << map[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        //Передвижение и ввод
        cin >> action;
        if (action == "d" && map[y][x+1] != "#") {
            map[y][x] = "*";
            x++;
            map[y][x] = "X";
        }
        if (action == "a" && map[y][x-1] != "#") {
            map[y][x] = "*";
            x--;
            map[y][x] = "X";
        }
        if (action == "w" && map[y-1][x] != "#") {
            map[y][x] = "*";
            y--;
            map[y][x] = "X";
        }
        if (action == "s" && map[y+1][x] != "#") {
            map[y][x] = "*";
            y++;
            map[y][x] = "X";
        }
        
        
    } while (action != "exit");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Как можно регистрировать нажатия клавиш?` - Вы хотите обрабатывать нажатия клавиш без std::cin с нажатием enter?

Comment: 1 и 2 — средствами **стандартного** C++ — ни как; только средствами конкретной ОС или сторонних библиотек. конкретики ради, см. `conio.h` или `curses`; 3 — «улучшить»  — очень расплывчатое понятие, но, например, можно использовать матрицу `char`, а не строк…

Comment: KoVadim, да.
@Fat-Zer, спасибо. В плане улучшить - сократить количество строк

Comment: "улучшить" - так там есть как минимум 2 однотипных цикла, которые можно в функцию запихнуть

Answer (score 0):

Регистрировать нажатия клавиш можно через `getchar`:

```
char a = getchar();
```

где `a` - введенная вами буква (не её код, как в случае с `getch` в `conio.h`

Comment: RandomDice, мне необходимо регистрировать нажатие клавиш без ввода их в консоль. Либо я неправильно использую getchar, но все равно спасибо

Comment: Тогда забирайте conio.h ```curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zoelabbb/conio.h/master/conio.h -o /usr/include/conio.h```, и далее ```#include <conio.h>``` и классический getch)

Comment: С этим я уже разобрался, теперь хочу разобраться с тем, чтобы не выводить в консоль массив, а заменять им значения консоли